# Let's Encrypt certificate automatic installation and renewal without SSH access?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, cpanel, lets-encrypt

I have a website running on a shared hosting provider (ie. without SSH access). CPanel is installed. Is it possible to install (and just as importantly, renew) a Let's Encrypt certificate automatically without SSH access? Perhaps a CPanel plugin or cron job (for automatic renewals)?

Answer (score 1):

follow this tutorial to for auto renewal https://neurobin.org/docs/web/fully-automated-letsencrypt-integration-with-cpanel/

---

You can install Lets encrypt SSL using cPanel ssl/tls -->Install and Manage SSL for your site (HTTPS) --> Manage SSL Sites. To renew certificate you need to regenerate it using your account key and Certificate provided by Lestencrypt in first time. I have done successfully that on GreenGeeks shared hosting help of http://wayneoutthere.com/how-to-lets-encrypt-cpanel-shared-hosting/. You can use https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#crt to generate Certificates and copy to Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install SSL on your domain through cPanel >> Security >> SSL.

If you are unable to find this in your cPanel then you need to install SSL on your domain through WHM.

Answer (score -1):

You will need Let's Encrypt itself to be installed on the server before running any plugin or crontab job (specially that).

I doubt there is a way to do that without SSH connection, specially on a shared server.